# Set position of ImageButton for several display sizes without xml

Tags: java, android, button, layout, mapsforge

I am creating a navigation app for my bachelor-thesis using android and mapsforge library from openstreetmap.

In my MapView I have added some ImageButtons to offer more information and functionality. I have set the position of the buttons with .setX and .setY but this is not an optimal solution for different screen sizes.

How do I have to set the position of the buttons, so that they have their same position in different screen sizes?

Best Regards,

Eddi

Comment: Have you looked at using a RelativeLayout? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want your buttons to look similar on different screen sizes you could use [density-independent pixels](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence).

```
private float convertDipToPixels(Context context, float dip)
{
    float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    return scale * dip;
}
```

If you apply that to your margins, positions, and dimensions it should provide a consistent look. I'd strongly suggest layout files for this work, but if that's not an option this should do the trick.